# Why iOS CLLocation shows incorrect values?

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to calculate distance between 2 coordinates. For this I do:

```
func setupLocationManager() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let latitude = locations.last?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = locations.last?.coordinate.longitude

    let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
    let targetLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 41.4381022, longitude: 46.604910)

    let distance = myLocation.distanceFromLocation(targetLocation)
    print(distance)
}
```

I'm checking in Google Maps there are 13 km distance! But my app shows me 2-3 km!

How can I improve that?

Comment: What is the latitude and longitude you're seeing being passed to your method? This looks correct to me.

Comment: I put one coordinate by hand and detecting my own location. And want to calculate distance between 2 locations @Arclite

Comment: How are you checking on google maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google maps gives you the route distance between two locations, `CLLocation` gives you the birds-eye distance between two locations.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:):

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on a [working GPS app](https://github.com/lightbeard/GPS-Orienteering-Logger/blob/master/ViewController.m).

```
import CoreLocation

public class SwiftLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var latestCoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(ignore:String) {

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        latestCoord = locationManager.location!.coordinate

        super.init()

        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

        latestCoord = manager.location!.coordinate

    }

    public func getLatest() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return latestCoord
    }
}
```